# Update a User's Firebase password in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a `UITableViewController` and I'd like the user to be able to change their current password with a new one.

The view is very straight forward - 2 `UITextFields` where I'd like them to enter their current password and another one for their desired new password.

The problem is I cannot find in Firebase's documentation a method that does that. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

PS: Ignore that it says "Update your email", this will be fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**1. Change Password**

In Order to change password for Firebase User you do not need old password. You can do it by re-authenticating user and then updating password.

**i. Re-authenticate User:**

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var credential: AuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

**ii. Change Password**

Once user is re-authenticated use following method to Change password:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: password) { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

**2. Forgot Password**

To handle this case you can send password reset link to user's email. Use following method:

```
Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: email) { error in
  // ...
}
```

source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: for getting the credential you can use this line `var credential: AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: user?.email ?? "", password: password)`